# The function only goes up to 50000 in C

Tags: c

The problem is `g(n) = g(n-1) + gcd(n, g(n-1)) for n > 4`. `gcd` is great common divisor. `g(4) = 13`.
I need to find the `10^15th` element. I used this code but I can only find `50000th` or so.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
unsigned long long int gcd(unsigned long long int a, unsigned long long int b);
int main(){
    int i;
    unsigned long long int x = 5;
    static unsigned long long int g[1000000000000000];
    g[4] = 13;
    unsigned long long int y = pow(10,15);
while(x != y){                                                                                      
    g[x] = g[x-1] + gcd(x,g[x-1]);
    printf("%llu\n", g[x]); 
    printf("\n  %d   ", x);
    x++;

}

}

unsigned long long int gcd(unsigned long long int a, unsigned long long int b) 
{ 
    // Everything divides 0  
    if (a == 0) 
       return b; 
    if (b == 0) 
       return a; 

    // base case 
    if (a == b) 
        return a; 

    // a is greater 
    if (a > b) 
        return gcd(a-b, b); 
    return gcd(a, b-a); 
}
```

Comment: get rid of the humungous array. `while (x < 1000000) { newg = oldg + gcd(x, oldg); oldg = newg; x++; }`

Comment: I don't care what the problem is, a quadrillion unsigned long longs isn't going to be part of the solution.

Comment: @pmg it still stops at 50000.

Comment: `x` has type `unsigned long long`, using `"%d"` to print it is wrong.

Comment: `static unsigned long long int g[1000000000000000];` OMG, does your machine explode when you execute this?

Comment: @WilliamPursell No, that array is only a small fraction of 64 bit virtual address space, so OS just happily marks the highest allowed address the application requests as usual and doesn't notice anything funny. Problems only occur when trying to write so much data there that it all doesn't fit in memory and swap.

Comment: Even when I don't use any arrays and type the datatypes right, it still gets to 50k something and stops. What should I do?

Comment: I rewrote the `gcd()` function. [My attempt](https://ideone.com/3nO4UL) appears to go well past 50000 without any problems.

Comment: where did you learn of this sequence? I couldn't find any reference to it in a quick internet search. Thanks

Comment: @pmg it's an assignment from our lecturer at the university

Comment: @pmg okay but it can't get over to 10^15. I need to make it faster somehow.

Comment: I suspect there may be some function that calculates the final value without having to calculate all previous ones. Something like `n + numberofprimesbelow(n) + ...`, can't help you with that.

Comment: You run out of stack with the recursive call of `gcd`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie perhaps [tail call gcd](https://ideone.com/QLRYn3)?

Comment: @pmg, yes, compiler could do that (turn it into a jump)

Comment: I still couldnt get it to work on the required number. Is there anyone with a solution